# Integer programming Branch and Bound Method on C

Tags: methods, integer-programming, branch-and-bound

I'm flashing a board where I need to use an algorithm that maximize an expression like
s = c1*x1 + c2*x2 + c3*x3 + c4*x4 subject to some constraints.

For example
Maximize p = x+y subject to x+y <= 2, 3x+y >= 4
Optimal Solution: p = 2; x = 1, y = 1

there is a free code to use somewhere?

Thank you

Comment: Do you still need a solution?

Comment: At the end I implemented an algorithm that uses the simplex algorithm and imposes binary variables with branch and bound.

Answer (score 0):

GLPK library is what you need.